# How to print from match to end of file?

Tags: awk

I have a input:

```
 achil           1   234671.82694245825        234671.82694245825       0.43995134290095084     
 achil           2   234671.82694245825        234671.82694245825       0.43995134290095084     
o 0  1 0 1 1      5.732820000     0.000 = PERIOD(0)
4
5
6
1
2
```

I would like to print from line with `o 0  1 0 1 1      5.732820000     0.000 = PERIOD(0)` to end of the file.

Desired output:

```
o 0  1 0 1 1      5.732820000     0.000 = PERIOD(0)
4
5
6
1
2
```

I tried:

```
awk '/o 0\s+1 0 1 1\s+5.732820000\s+0.000 = PERIOD(0)/,/*/' input > output
```

and the output is an empty file. What is wrong please?

Comment: I do this code according this question, but there is a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
awk '/o 0  1 0 1 1/,0' input
```

Consider this one liner `awk /pattern1/,/pattern2/' input`. It matches all the lines starting with a line that matches "`pattern1`" and continuing until a line matches "`pattern2`" (inclusive).

In this one-liner "`pattern1`" is "`o 0  1 0 1 1`" and "`pattern2`" is just `0` (false). So this one-liner prints all lines starting from a line that matches "`o 0  1 0 1 1`" continuing to end-of-file (because 0 is always false, and "`pattern2`" never matches)

[Reference](https://catonmat.net/awk-one-liners-explained-part-three)

Answer (score 2):

This may also do:

```
awk '/o 0  1 0 1 1/ {f=1} f' file
o 0  1 0 1 1      5.732820000     0.000 = PERIOD(0)
4
5
6
1
2
```

When pattern is found, set flag `f` to true. 
When flag `f` is true, do default action, print